# Changing time format and zone on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, timezone

I have an application that currently parses data from a server. Inside the data there are various dates for various events. The thing is that the application will be international so i would like when the date is downloaded to the phone from the server through an xml file to be in the correct zone.

All the dates i have are in GMT+2. The format of my dates is(example) : `21:45 31-08-2012 GMT+2`

Is it possible somehow if the users phone is in an different time zone , for example GMT+4 , to change the time automatically so that the user could see the correct time? How would that look programaticaly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common practice is to use UNIX EPOCH (with no timezone information) to convey information from/to your clients. The conversion can then be done when displaying a date in a particular locale using:

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:ephochValue];
```

Comment: wow you are completely right! :D so i just sent from my server the UNIX EPOCH and i have my application translate it like you said and will always be in the phones local time , right?

Comment: Yes, I also suggest that you store unix epoch time in the database as well. I've done this many times and it really solves a lot of timezone and daytime changes issues.